# Decompile apk game built in corona sdk

Tags: lua, sdk, coronasdk, game-development

A long time ago, I and a friend did a mini-game with corona sdk. We lost the source code and this week I finded the apk lost here.

I tried extract the .apk with ApkTool (https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/) and I got the imagens and sounds inside the assets folder. also inside it, I have a file resource.car compiled, but when open with notes I can see a little of the lua code. I think it's the code file.

[IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B18Vb.png)

I can extract the code? How to do that? We really wish to continue developing the game.

Comment: Lua is usually not compiled so maybe it is just compressed. Can you identify what type of file this .car is? It may be an archive.

Comment: I don't know.. what you mean with type? I've openned with notepad++ and HexEditor

Comment: The type of this file, or the software which created this particular file. The first 4 bytes are often an indicator for the file type. I never heard of this extension and a quick google search did not help me either. Can you share the apk so I can take a look at it?

Comment: I followed this issue on github and got a .lu files (https://github.com/0BuRner/corona-archiver/issues/3). After, I used a Lua decompile here (https://lua-decompiler.ferib.dev/) on files and the source codes. Nevertheless, the code appears with strange names of variables (l_1_0, l_1_6, l_2_0 ... ) and the biggest file doesn't descompile.. it's corrupted. If the biggest file can be descompile successfully, maybe I can rewrite all the code changing the variables. I think is more easy I share the resource.car with you, yah?

Comment: Oh my, if you need a decompiler it's bad. During compilations variable names get lost, so you have to deal with weird names :(
You can send me the .car and I can see if I can make it running again, but you may need to work with very ugly code.

Comment: Yeah, it's true.. but if I can descompile the biggest one file called game.lu maybe I can rewrite the game, no problem..
By the way, here is the resource.car file, take a look :)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/133S2IK28DhINvbpppMq6GWbu10IB2kj5/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `resources.car` is a Corona specific archive.

Using https://github.com/0BuRner/corona-archiver it can be extracted.

Corona compiles the Lua files, `file file.lua` returns Lua 5.1 but most decompiler fail for unknown reasons.

The software `unluac` (https://sourceforge.net/projects/unluac/) managed to decompile all files. `game.lua` has an invalid goto location but aside that all files should execute. Untested as I do not have Corona installed.

Here is the decompiled source https://mega.nz/file/7sRACCSK#XiEosryl5jesG6uPeJdOqFsE8fLWDfmGSCOh-cTuHpk

Since the code is barely readable after decompile, you may need to rewrite it anyways, but maybe you can confirm whether it works.

Comment: Perfect! It's what I have been waiting.. Thanks a lot buddy!